# Column is not updating in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I tried to update my table like below:

```
         $query = "select *
                   FROM sites s, companies c, tests t 
                   WHERE t.test_siteid = s.site_id 
                   AND c.company_id = s.site_companyid 
                   AND t.test_typeid = '20' AND s.site_id = '1337'";

            $queryrow  = $db->query($query);
            $results = $queryrow->as_array();  

            foreach($results as $key=>$val){
                    $update = "update tests set test_typeid = ? , test_testtype = ? where test_siteid = ?";
                    $queryrow  = $db->query($update,array('10','Meter Calibration Semi Annual',$val->site_id));
            }
```

The above code is working good. But in update query , The column test_typeid is not updated with **'10'**. Column test_typeid is updating with empty value. Other columns are updating good. I dont know why this column test_typeid is not updating? And the column test_typeid type is **integer** only. I am using **postgreSql**

And My table definition is:

[image]

What i did wrong with the code. Kindly advice me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show us the definition for table 'tests'

Comment: @Meiko I attached definition of my table. Please refer

Comment: try $queryrow  = $db->query($update,array(10,'Meter Calibration Semi Annual',$val->site_id));

Comment: @Meiko Yes I tried. It is updating empty value to the column.

Comment: Have you tried to change type of `test_typeid` to `varchar`? Did you try to set some value there and then update it with that script to see if it will remove value?

Comment: Have the same issue, BIGINT columns are not updated, did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause; always use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.

You can write the query in one statement:

```
update tests t
    set test_typeid = '10',
        test_testtype = 'Meter Calibration Semi Annual'
from sites s join
     companies c
     on c.company_id = s.site_companyid 
where t.test_siteid = s.site_id and
      t.test_typeid = 20 and s.site_id = 1337;
```

I assume the ids are numbers, so there is no need to use single quotes for the comparisons.

Comment: I have tried **Already** the query with proper join. Anyway it was not working. So i just wrote the query as simple as i can. yours and mine are same. there is no problem in joins. I need a solution for not updating column. the column is integer but not updating. I removed the quotes too and tried. it is not working still.